# Configure Liferay to Allow Single Sign On Across http://aaa.com and http://www.aaa.com

Tags: session, cross-domain, liferay, single-sign-on

I would like to know how to configure my Liferay 6.1 application to enable SSO (Single Sign On) across my domain and subdomain. 
Currently when a user signs into either my domain or its sub-domain, the session does not cut across the other one. For example, my domain and sub-domains are http://john.com and http://www.john.com.

When Logging into http://john.com a session is created for me. I find that if I typed http://www.john.com in my browser while the session is still active, the session is not maintained. Same applies vice versa.

Again how do I configure my Liferay 6.1 application to enable SSO (Single Sign On) across my domain and subdomain.

Thanks

Comment: This looks more like an issue with your SSO product than with Liferay. Which SSO product are you using with Liferay?

Comment: @Thakkar
I am using CAS.

Comment: Can you provide your Liferay CAS configuration for reference?

Comment: Did you found the solution for this??

Comment: Hi Bhavin, Nope I didnt due to the company no longer needed that implementation. Hope you are able to find a solution.